# Orange bar vanishing without interaction

Tags: support, notification-bar

I've recently edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831813/image-segmentation-using-mean-shift-explained/4835340#4835340) I posted some time ago.

After committing the changes, I got an orange bar that started with something like "Be advised ...", but it vanished by itself too quickly to finish reading it.

As the answer is reaching its Community-Wiki threshold, I think the warning could be related to that.

I am not sure how to reproduce the issue without risking a real community wiki shift, and I don't want to report it as a bug yet as I don't have enough info (just two "may be" words).

Are there any previous reports on this that I am not able to find in meta?
Any ideas to repro the situation without risking content?

Platform: Firefox 3.6.6/WinXP.